# Zookeeper watches :: No notification in case of child node modification

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We are seeing an issue with zookeeper watches. We creating a node “/newtest” and intent is to add/modify nodes inside it. We are putting a watch on "/newtest”. Our observation is that if a child is added or deleted we get the notification **but if a child is modified we do not get the notification**.

Below is the output from zkCli.sh commands

========

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 21] ls  /newtest watch      **<=== to get the child nodes plus the watch**

[1, 5, 4]  <=== 1,5, 4 are the child nodes

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 24] set /newtest/5 hello6  **<=== updating the data for node “5”, no watch notification**

cZxid = 0xc16

ctime = Fri Mar 11 01:03:29 UTC 2016

mZxid = 0xc78

mtime = Fri Mar 11 01:19:48 UTC 2016

pZxid = 0xc16

cversion = 0

dataVersion = 2

aclVersion = 0

ephemeralOwner = 0x0

dataLength = 6

numChildren = 0

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 25] create /newtest/6 hello6 **<=== creating a new node**

WATCHER::

Created /newtest/6

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeChildrenChanged path:/newtest  **<== watcher notification**

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 26] ls  /newtest watch      **<=== Again watch**

[1, 6, 5, 4]

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 27] set /newtest/6 hello6   **<== updating node “6”, no notification**

cZxid = 0xc79

ctime = Fri Mar 11 01:19:59 UTC 2016

mZxid = 0xc86

mtime = Fri Mar 11 01:23:18 UTC 2016

pZxid = 0xc79

cversion = 0

dataVersion = 1

aclVersion = 0

ephemeralOwner = 0x0

dataLength = 6

numChildren = 0

========

Please suggest a solution. Zookeeper version is zookeeper.version=3.4.6--1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using zkCli.sh for anything other than testing and small/quick operations. If you want to get notifications when a child node is modified I would suggest writing your own watchers in Java using [Apache Curator](http://curator.apache.org/), and more specifically using a [Tree Cache](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/tree-cache.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Cli was a triage,  for development we are using Golang and there also same issue was faced.

Comment: We are using https://github.com/samuel/gozookeeper library and ChildrenW() to watch for child operation notifications. There also we observed that child modification do not get notified.

Comment: I have not tried zookeeper from Golang, but would still suggest using Curator, it's much easier than trying to handle all the corner-cases by yourselves. Have a look at https://godoc.org/github.com/flier/curator.go , I have unfortunately not used Curator with Golang.